# PHP connect to FTP server

Tags: php, mysql

hello I have my code that connects to my ftp server

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name";
exit;
} else {
echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
//ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dir);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
//var_dump($contents);
echo "<select name=\"file\">\n";
// Now loop through the files, echoing out a new select option for each one
if (($contents != '.')  && ($contents != '..') ) 
{

foreach( $contents as $fname )

{
   echo "<option>{$fname}</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";

}
}
```

but the page is still echoing back the directories as . & .. despite the $contents != bit; what is missing?

changed to this ->

```
if (($fname != '.')  && ($fname != '..') ) 
{

foreach( $contents as $fname )

{
   echo "<option>{$fname}</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";

}
}
```

but still same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to compare `$fname` inside the loop against being `.` or `..`. This is probably more what you want.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, is it not being compared to as it is now?

Comment: Now, you are comparing `$contents` – which happens to be an array, so it will never be equal to `'.'` or `'..'`. But what you want to be doing is comparing the elements of that array, so the comparison needs to be `if ($fname != '.' && $fname != '..')` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: It needs to be INSIDE the foreach.

`foreach ($contents as $fname) { 
if ($fname != '.' && $fname != '..') {